# JavaScript array contains one of value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Example array:

```
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"];
```

Array with requires:

```
var array2 = ["d", "g", "j", "k"];
```

So it will return `true` if `array1` contains at least one value from `array2`. Can you help me with that?

**Note:** `array1` may contains all four values from `array2`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript

Comment: @ArkarAung it is similar and also it can solve my problem, but I wanted something simpler than your suggestion. Anyway, it doesn't work like I want, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/debute/vfse5ddu/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something as simple as:

```
function Contains(array1, array2)
{
    for(var i=0; i<array2.length; i++)
        if(array1.indexOf(array2[i])>-1)
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Initially you loop through the items of `array2`. If one item of `array2` is found in the `array1` you return true. Otherwise you return false.

Comment: `for (var item in array2)` is used with objects, not arrays. And `item` will be the keys, not the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        if(array1[i] === array2[j]) {
            return true
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = array2.length;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    if (array1.indexOf(array2[i] !== -1) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: @meskobalazs Oops wrongly typed. Yup `length`. Updated